# Android: How to create a menu button like google keep

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button, floating-action-button, google-keep

how to create a menu button like google keep app android, with action: after pressing the menu button show the other options of menu.

how keep the menu button be always visible on the screen?

how to create that effect after the click?

this image can clarify things
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9ZjtpUDZajFNFM2bnBuOTNsX2c/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Are we supposed to download that app and see for ourselves or would you kindly provide a screenshot?

Comment: talking about a floating action button (elevated circular button at the bottom rigth) :)

Comment: the screenshot image https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9ZjtpUDZajFNFM2bnBuOTNsX2c/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are talking about a floating action button (elevated circular button at the bottom rigth), this [library](https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button) provides a nice implementation of it called `FloatingActionsMenu`. You can find some other libraries as well like [this](https://github.com/clans/FloatingActionButton).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Android Guidelines by Google.

ActionBar: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html